# I need spring framework xml schema

Tags: spring, configuration

I'm trying to execute a small spring application in my eclipse ide.I have downloaded the spring-framework-4.1 zip file. I want xml schema to put it in my spring.xml file.where can i get the schema from the downloaded zip file?
thanks.

Comment: If you're new to spring I'd recommend using Spring-Boot.  You can add SpringBoot starter dependencies to your Maven POM or Gradle file and it will automatically configure everything to defaults.  You can then make modifications and add your own configuration files to customize anything that you don't want defaulted:  http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/

Comment: If you are a beginner at spring download Spring Tool Suite and create Spring project. It's better and simple. Url : https://spring.io/tools/sts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the xsd schemas come in one of the packaged within the jar files, for example within `org.springframework.beans.factory.xml` there are the spring-beans-X.X.xsd files, try to search the entire zip looking for the files that ends with .xsd.

Sometimes the xsd files are contained within the config packages for example.

```
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config
```

I should recomment to use STS it can be create the namespace configuration on behalf you, just clicking in the namespace tab and add what you required.

Or you can download from [here](https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/4.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-4.1.0.RELEASE-schema.zip), but again I should recommend use maven to download dependencies.